# Need help understanding morphisms of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So far, in my course we have talked about affine algebraic varieties, then about prevarieties, and finally about algebraic varieties and projective varieties. Here is what I understand so far (please correct me if anything I say here is wrong):

1. An affine algebraic variety over $k$ is a solution set of some set of polynomial equations over a field $k$ (eg. $V = \{ (a_1 , \dots , a_n) \in k^n ; f(a_1 , \dots , a_n) = 0 \ \forall f \in a \}$ for some ideal $\mathcal{a} \subset k[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$. A morphism of affine varieties $V \to W$ corresponds to a ring homomorphism of their respective coordinate rings $k[W] \to k[V]$. We were given some analogous definitions of affine varieties (eg. description as the space of maximal ideals of a $k$-algebra) which I do not understand very well.
2. A prevariety is a $k$-ringed space $(V, \mathcal{O}_V)$ with a finite open (with respect to Zariski topology) covering $V =\bigcup U_i$ such that $(U_i, \mathcal{O}_V |_{U_i})$ is an affine algebraic variety over $k$.
3. An algebraic variety is a prevariety with some additional separation type condition.
4. A projective variety is an algebraic variety which is a closed (with respect to Zariski topology) subset of the projective space $\mathbf{P}_k^n$ ($n$-dimensional projective space over field $k$).

Now in our lecture notes, my professor states that a morphism of algebraic varieties $V \to W$ is simply a morphism of ringed spaces, which we defined to be a regular map $\phi: V \to W$ and a family of $k$-algebra homomorphisms:

\begin{equation}
\phi_U : \mathcal{O}_W(U) \to \mathcal{O}_V(\phi^{-1}(U))
\end{equation}

for every open subset $U$ of $W$, which commute with the restriction maps (?).

However, this definition is very abstract and was given with very few concrete examples. For example, let us say I wanted to define an automorphism of the projective spaces $\phi: \mathbf{P}_\mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbf{P}_\mathbb{R}^1$. How would I do so using this definition? I know it has to be a bijective map on the points, but how can I make sense of the 2nd condition? What confuses me here is that we have no notion of coordinate rings like we do in the case of affine varieties.

Comment: Projective varieties, being algebraic varieties, have a sheaf of rings as part of their definition. Also, for the definition of affine algebraic variety you use, you need $k$ to be algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "For example, let us say I wanted to define an automorphism of the projective spaces ϕ:P1R→P1R. How would I do so using this definition?"

**Answer:** There is a calculation in Hartshorne Ex.II.7.1.1 of the automorphism group of the projective line. Let $k$ be the real numbers and $V^*:=k\{x_0,x_1\}$ and $C:=Proj(k[x_0,x_1])$. Any matrix $\phi^* \in GL(2,k)$ induce an automorphism

$$\phi^*: k[x_0,x_1] \rightarrow k[x_0,x_1].$$

You must check that the automorphism $\phi$ induce an automorphism

$$\phi: C \rightarrow C$$

defined over $k$. This is because the map $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism at the graded components

$$\phi^*_d:k[x_0,x_1]_d \rightarrow k[x_0,x_1]_d$$

for all $d \geq 0$. Hence by HH.Ex.II.2.14 it follows the induced map $\phi$ is an automorphism.
If $\psi:= \lambda Id(2)$ with $\lambda \in k^*$ and $Id(2)$ the $2\times 2$-identity matrix, it follows $\psi$ induce the identity automorphism of $C$. The automorphisms $\phi$ and $\phi + \lambda Id(2)$ induce the same automorphism of $C$, hence the quotient group $PGL(2,k):=GL(2,k)/k^*$ is a subgroup of the group $Aut_k(C)$ of automorphisms of $C$. In Ex.II.7.1.1 they prove that these are all automorphisms of the projective line. Any automorphism $\phi$ over $k$ must have the property that $\phi^*(\mathcal{O}(1))=\mathcal{O}(1)$ since $\phi$ induce an automorphism of the Picard group $Pic(C)$. The map $\phi$ must induce an automorphism of $H^0(C, \mathcal{O}(1))$ which is a 2-dimensional vector space over $k$ and it follows from Theorem II.7.1 that $\phi$ is induced by an element of $PGL(2,k)$.

There is a relation between maps $\phi: C \rightarrow C$ and line bundle quotients

$$\phi_L:\pi^*(V^*) \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0$$

(see Proposition II.7.12) and this result and Thm II.7.1 is needed for the calculation of $Aut_k(C)$.

**Note:** The projective line $C$ has an open cover

$$D(x_0):=Spec(k[t])\text{ and }D(x_1):=Spec(k[s])$$

with $t:=x_1/x_0, s:=1/t$ and $$D(x_0) \cap D(x_1) \cong Spec(k[t,s]).$$

Any map $\psi:Spec(A) \rightarrow Spec(A)$ induce for any element $a\in A$ a map

$$\phi_a: D(a):=Spec(A_a) \rightarrow D(\phi(a)):=Spec(A_{\phi(a)})$$

If $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $S:=Spec(A)$ it follows by construction

$$Aut_k(S) \cong Aut_{k-alg}(A),$$

hence to construct an automorphism of $k$-schemes of $S$ is equivalent to constructing a $k$-algebra automorphism of $A$. It is not immediate how to calculate the automorphism group $Aut_k(C)$ of $C$ using the open cover above: An automorphism $\phi$ may not fix the open sets $D(x_i)$.

This calculation requires knowledge about sheaves and linebundles.

**Coordinatewise:** If you define the real projective line $C(k)$ as the set of equivalence classes $x:=(a_0:a_1) \in k^2-\{(0,0)\}$ with $(a_0:a_1) \cong (\lambda a_0:\lambda a_1)$ with $\lambda \in k^*$, given any matrix $g \in GL(2,k)$ you may define

$$gx:=(aa_0+ba_1:ca_0+da_1)$$

and since $g$ is an invertible matrix it follows $gx\in C(k)$ is a well defined element. This defines for any matrix $g\in GL(2,k)$ an automorphism (over $k$)

$$g: C(k) \rightarrow C(k)$$

with inverse $g^{-1}$. The maps $g$ and $g+ \lambda Id(2)$ where $\lambda \in k^*$ and $Id(2)$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix induce the same map, and hence you get a map

$$ \rho: PGL(2,k):=GL(2,k)/\{\lambda Id(2)\} \rightarrow Aut_k(C(k))$$

If you are to do everything rigorously in the language of "schemes" things become more complicated.